# How can I prevent a screen reader/narrator from reading controls that are hidden in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, automation, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a WPF application, which needs to support accessibility. I have a TextBlock that under certain conditions has its Visibility set to Collapsed.

The Windows 7 narrator and also [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org/) screen reader both announce the TextBlock even so the Visibility is set to Collapsed.

What do I need to do to prevent it from being read?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I hide them using the automation peer classes https://thinkrethink.net/2019/02/11/wpf-narrator-reads-collapsed-content/

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility-tools-docs/items/WPF/Control_IsControlElement#suggested-fix):

> In versions of .NET earlier than 4.8, it is expected that when a
> Button is hidden or collapsed, the Button UI continues to be exposed
> through the Control view of the UIA tree, as a Button element and a
> child Text element. As such, a screen reader may navigate to both
> those elements, despite the Button having no visual representation. In
> .NET version 4.8, when a Button is hidden or collapsed, the associated
> Button element and Text element are removed from the Control view of
> the UIA tree. Please consider whether it is practical for your app to
> leverage this improvement made available in .NET version 4.8.
>
> To leverage the fix introduced with .NET 4.8 either rebuild your app
> to target version 4.8 or later, or update your app's config file such
> that the app will leverage the improvement if a version of .NET with
> the improvement is installed on the device where the app is run, even
> if your app has not been rebuilt to specifically target that version
> of .NET.
>
> To learn more about how you can configure your app to leverage an
> accessibility-related fix available in a specific version of .NET,
> even when your app has not been rebuilt to target that version of
> .NET, visit [Accessibility switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/whats-new-in-accessibility#accessibility-switches).

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to Disable them?
It's quite some time ago since I last worked on WPF accessibility :-(

Answer (score -2):

Add the aria-hidden="true" attribute to your element. aria-hidden indicates that the element and all of its descendants are not visible or perceivable to any user as implemented by the author.

You will need to remove this attribute (or set it to false) when your content becomes visible.

AT support was spotty a couple of years ago but it's 100% now, see the table here: http://terrillthompson.com/tests/hiddencontent.html

Comment: That's good advice but only applicable to html applications.  The original question was about a WPF app.